# can't run graph with command rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello! I'm new to this site and ROS
I just finished installing ros and wanted to get some graph...

so I just typed the command

```
rqt_plot rqt_plot
```

this logs got showed up

```
$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1015: UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1025: UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
  warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/mat_data_plot.py", line 107, in resizeEvent
    self.figure.tight_layout()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1754, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 349, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 128, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    fig.transFigure.inverted())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1775, in inverted
    self._inverted = Affine2D(inv(mtx), shorthand_name=shorthand_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 526, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I don't know why I get this error... I think I installed ROS properly...
Could someone please give me a hand to solve this error..
and just nevermind that tags.. I am the first time in here so I don't know how to include tags properly..
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS is kinetic and 1.12.14

Thank you for your hand in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347215/can%27t-run-graph-with-command-rosrun-rqt_plot-rqt_plot/) by [kimbap](https://answers.ros.org/users/52748/kimbap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-21**:\

> and just nevermind that tags.. I am the first time in here so I don't know how to include tags properly..

so you don't know which ROS version you are using?

**Comment by [kk9612](https://answers.ros.org/users/52849/kk9612/) on 2020-03-25**:
I also have such an error.  Did you solve it?

**Comment by [kimbap](https://answers.ros.org/users/52748/kimbap/) on 2020-03-25**:
I didn't solve this problem yet....

**Comment by [dennisjm](https://answers.ros.org/users/52862/dennisjm/) on 2020-03-25**:
I was running the same tutorial and got that error. Looking at the documentation for rqt_plot, it uses pyqtgraph first (preferable), then resorts to matplotlib if pyqtgraph is not installed. Try pip installing pyqtgraph, it worked for me! Not sure what the issue is with matplotlib though...

**Comment by [kimbap](https://answers.ros.org/users/52748/kimbap/) on 2020-04-23**:
one of my friend told me that I can run plot
type "rqt" and "plugins-visualization-plot" then you can use the plot graph and someone just answered my question XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can just invoke the `rqt_plot` by running

> rqt

which will open the Standard GUI

and then traverse through `plugins->Visualization->Plot`  to get the MatPlot

FYI : this is kinda workaround !!! works for this tutorial, I think one should give a more concrete solution

---

Originally posted by [raiakash](https://answers.ros.org/users/53145/raiakash/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kimbap](https://answers.ros.org/users/52748/kimbap/) on 2020-04-23**:
wow thank you for your answer! I already solved that but I think it will be reallky helpful for other people struggling with this :D

**Comment by [hassaanaero](https://answers.ros.org/users/64113/hassaanaero/) on 2021-01-04**:
@kimbap how were you  able to solve this problem??